# DateFormat does not work?

Tags: java, date, format

```
String selectedDate = "2012-" + createdMonth + "-" + createdDay;

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

try {
    createdDate = dateFormat.parse(selectedDate);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(createdDate);
```

Basically when I print createdDate, it will display something like this :
Thu Mar 08 00:00:00 CST 2012

Instead of something of this format "yyyy-MM-dd". Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Date has a default format which you have seen.  If you want to display it in a particular format you need to use that DateFormat again to convert it back to the String to parsed. (Which is a little pointless of course)

Answer (score 2):

The `parse` method returns a `java.util.Date` and that is the what the `Date` implementation of `toString()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print as below. Point is that you need to use the formatter object you have created while printing as well.

```
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(createdDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `dateFormat.format(createdDate)`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that `createdDate`, which is a `Date` object, has the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. It doesn't. `Date` objects don't have a format - they just contain a timestamp, just like numbers are just numbers, which don't have a format by themselves.

A `SimpleDateFormat` object is used to parse a `String` into a `Date` object, or format a `Date` object into a `String`.

If you have a `Date` object and you want to display the date in a particular format, then convert it to a `String` with the appropriate format using a `SimpleDateFormat` object:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String text = fmt.format(createdDate);
System.out.println("Created: " + text);
```

If you print a `Date` object without explicitly formatting it, it will be formatted using a default format, which is why you see `Thu Mar 08 00:00:00 CST 2012`.

A `Date` object does not somehow remember what the format was of the `String` that you parsed it from.